# The longest chain of subgroups for real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I would like to know what is the longest possible chain of subgroups starting from the group of real invertible matrices.
Of course, I suppose there many possible chains, but the most valuable, let's assume, would be that  with the greatest number of subgroups.

My initial proposition is as follows:

1. Group of invertible real matrices $GL_n(R)$
2. Subgroup of invertible real matrices with rational determinant.
3. Subgroup of invertible real matrices with determinant equal to $1$ or $-1$.
4. Subgroup of orthogonal matrices.
5. Subgroup of rotation matrices (determinant equal to $1$)
6. Subgroup of rotation matrices with rational elements.
7. Subgroup of rotation matrices with elements only $1,0,-1$.

I hope all the listed subgroups are satisfying definition of subgroup.
So we have group  $GL_n(R)$  and 6 subgroups where every listed group is a subgroup of **it's predecessor**. Such list I name a chain.

Can we present a longer chain of subgroups?

It is allowable to increase resolution of the given chain (if it is possible) or to give other longer chain, starting from $GL_n(R)$.
Parallel branches are not allowable, only single simple chain.

Comment: Do you want normal subgroups or just any subgroup? If you only want subgroups you can either consider blockmatrices (to gain arbitrary long chains depending on n) or you can consider invertible matrices over increasing numberfields, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}]$.

Comment: @ctst Just any subgroup. I,m not searching for large dimensions matrices. ( for easy presentation on the blackboard) Let say is up to $4$ dimension.

Comment: To add a bit to what @user1551 has said, maybe you should deal with the case of $\mathbb{R}^*=GL(1,\mathbb{R})$ first.

Comment: $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ contains a copy of $\Bbb R$ (namely, the image of the embedding $\lambda\mapsto e^{\lambda}I$). With AC, $\Bbb R$ is the $\Bbb Q$-vector space of dimension $\beth_1$, therefore by selecting the appropriate subsets of a Hamel basis as generators you can realise every total order in $(\mathcal P(\Bbb R),\subseteq)$ as an inclusion of subgroups. This includes, for instance, $(\Bbb R,\le)$ and the ordinal $\beth_1$.

Comment: @user1551 Even if the size of matrix would be limited to a relatively small number, say $4$, What is the method for such construction? This method would be allowing also to include in it the chain presented in the question?

Comment: Well, (6) is countable and (7) is finite, so you certainly can't have uncountable chains in (6) or longer than $2^nn!$ in (7).

Comment: A better question is about chains of closed connected subgroups. Then at least there is a finite upper bound.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Very interesting, could you elaborate answer also with this condition?  (or to officially post this question..). Yes, I was expecting chains with a finite upper bound, but unexpectedly for me infinite chains have occurred..

Comment: Such subgroups are determined by their Lie algebras. The Lie algebra of $GL(n,R)$ has dimension $n^2$, hence, a crude upper bound on the lengths of such chains will be $n^2+1$ since this is the length of a longest chain of linear subspaces in a $n^2$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: A lower bound is also quadratic (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29087/commutative-subalgebras-of-m-n)), but I do not know the exact asymptotics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exists an infinitely long chain of increasing subgroups $G_1 \trianglelefteq G_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$
such that each $G_i$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$. For example consider an infinite sequence $\mathbb{K}_1 \subsetneq \mathbb{K}_2 \subsetneq \dots$ of numberfields. Then the set
$$G_i:=\{A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \mid det(A) \in K_i\}$$
is a normal subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and a proper subgroup of $G_{i+1}$.

Comment: Could you give the example of some subchain (longer than 6) of this supposed infinite chain for $GL_2(R)$

Comment: @Widawensen For example, take $\Bbb K_i = \Bbb Q[2^{1/(2^i)}] = \Bbb Q[\sqrt[(2^i)]{2}]$

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Interesting, but if I would add one additional constraint for  the chain, namely that it should include orthogonal matrices, how it would influence a solution?

Comment: The given chain already includes all orthogonal matrices, as they have to have determinant $\pm 1$. (Ben beat me to the example, wanted to give the exact same sequence ;-) )

Comment: @ctst  I do not understand, how from the formula above could be generated all orthogonal matrices?

Comment: An orthogonal matrix has to have determinant 1 or -1. Since $\pm 1 \in \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{K}_i$ we have in particular, that $O_2 \leq G_1$, so you can just extend your chain at the beginning with $O_2$.

Comment: @ctst Probably you are right, maybe the method is a little too abstract for me. If I could see a concrete chain of matrices probably it would be easier for me to grasp a concept..

Comment: An easy example would be to follow ancient mathematicians hint and just look at $n=1$. There, any matrix is just a real number (as a $1 \times 1$ matrix) and the groups are of the form $$G_i:=\{ \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} q_i \cdot 2^{\frac{j}{i}} \neq 0 \mid q_i \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$$ Just check, that $G_i$ with the typical multiplication is indeed a group (the inverse is probably a little bit hard).

Comment: @ctst Yes, multiplication gives the result of the presented form. Thank you for the explanation. Orthogonal "matrices" in this case I suppose are just numbers $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Yes, you got that right!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to construct an infinite chain because $\mathbb R$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

In your comments, you seem to be interested in chains descending from $O(n,\mathbb R)$ or $SO(n,\mathbb R)$. Here are a few examples.

1. Denote by $R_\theta$ the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for an angle $\theta$. Define
   $$
   G_k=\{R_{m\pi/2^{k-2}}\oplus I_{n-2}:m\in\mathbb Z\}
   $$
   for each $k\ge1$. Then each $G_k$ is a group and
   $$
   GL(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq O(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq SO(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq G_k\supsetneq G_{k-1}\supsetneq\cdots\supsetneq G_1.
   $$
   This chain is finite but it can be made arbitrarily long.
2. For a genuine infinite chain, pick any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ that is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, such as $\alpha=\pi$. If we define $F_k=\mathbb Q[\alpha^k]$ for each $k\ge1$, [a simple argument](https://math.stacke%5Calphachange.com/a/1132659) shows that
   $$
   \mathbb R\supsetneq F_1\supsetneq F_2\supsetneq\cdots.
   $$
   Now, if we define for each $k\ge1$
   $$
   G_k=\{R_{2\pi x}\oplus I_{n-2}:x\in F_k\},
   $$
   then $G_k$ is a group and
   $$
   GL(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq O(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq SO(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq G_1\supsetneq G_2\supsetneq\cdots.\tag{$\dagger$}
   $$
3. For a more sophisticated example, let $U_k$ be the set of all orthogonal matrices obtained from Cayley transforms of skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrices over $F_k$, i.e.,
   $$
   U_k=\{(I-A)^{-1}(I+A):A\in M_n(F_k),\ A=-A^T\}\subset SO(n,F_k)\subset M_n(F_k).
   $$
   Let $G_k\subset M_n(F_k)$ be the free group generated from $U_k$. Then
   $$
   \left(I_n-\pmatrix{0&-\alpha^k\\ \alpha^k&0\\ &&I_{n-2}}\right)^{-1}
   \left(I_n+\pmatrix{0&-\alpha^k\\ \alpha^k&0\\ &&I_{n-2}}\right)
   =\pmatrix{\frac{1-\alpha^{2k}}{1+\alpha^{2k}}&-\frac{2\alpha^k}{1+\alpha^{2k}}\\ \frac{2\alpha^k}{1+\alpha^{2k}}&\frac{1-\alpha^{2k}}{1+\alpha^{2k}}\\ &&I_{n-2}}
   $$
   belongs to $G_k\setminus M_n(F_{k+1})$. Hence $G_k\supsetneq G_{k+1}$. For a similar reason, we also have $SO(n,\mathbb R)\supsetneq G_1$. Hence $(\dagger)$ again holds.

Comment: So it is possible to generate infinite chain in this way. I didn't expect there is a method. Very impressive.